# How can Ι align the items in enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate

I use the enumerate environment and I wanted some items to be in the same line with horizontal numbering. I don't want use the `multicol` or `tasks` packages and so I found the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\initem}{\ifnum\enit@type=\z@\refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
                     \hspace{20pt}\@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}}
\makeatother
```

but items have different width each time while the horizontal space between them is specific because of `\hspace` command. How can I get the right space each time so that items to be vertically aligned?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textheight=21cm,textwidth=16cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\initem}{\ifnum\enit@type=\z@\refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
                     \hspace{20pt}\@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Example 1 -- Two columns \\
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+5x-1$
    \initem $f(x)= \frac{x+3}{2x-4}$
    \item   $f(x)= \sqrt{3x-12}$
    \initem $f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{6-2x}}$
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{1cm}

Example 2 -- Three columns \\
\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.334\linewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+1$
    \initem $f(x)= \frac{x+3}{2x-4}$
    \initem $f(x)= \sqrt{3x-12}$
    \item   $f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$
    \initem $f(x)= \frac{x}{x+1}$
    \initem $f(x)= \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why you not like to use `tasks` package? It is designed for what you like to have ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\large\textbf{\arabic{enumi}{.}}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\alph{enumii}{)}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\enumlen}
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\setlength{\enumlen}{\linewidth}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\initem}[2][]{
    \ifx&#1&
        \ifnum\enit@type=\z@\refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
        \hfill
        \makebox[0.5\enumlen][l]
        {\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\@itemlabel}\hspace{\labelsep}{#2}}
    \else
        \ifnum\enit@type=\z@\refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
        \hfill
        \makebox[\dimexpr(\enumlen/3)][l]
        {\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\@itemlabel}\hspace{\labelsep}{#1}}%
        \ifnum\enit@type=\z@\refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
        \makebox[\dimexpr(\enumlen/3)][l]
        {\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\@itemlabel}\hspace{\labelsep}{#2}}
    \fi
}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
\hphantom{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}}\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
        \initem {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
        \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
        \initem {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
        \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
        \initem {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item
\rule{0.33333\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
\hphantom{\rule{0.33333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}\rule{0.33333\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
\hphantom{\rule{0.66666\linewidth}{0.5pt}}\rule{0.33333\linewidth}{0.5pt}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
        \initem [$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$]
                {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
        \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
        \initem [$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$]
                {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
        \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
        \initem [$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$]
                {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
        \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
        \initem [$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$]
                {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
        \item
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
\hphantom{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}}\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
            \initem {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
            \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
            \initem {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
            \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
            \initem {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
            \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
            \initem {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
            \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
            \initem {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item
\rule{0.33333\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
\hphantom{\rule{0.33333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}\rule{0.33333\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\
\hphantom{\rule{0.66666\linewidth}{0.5pt}}\rule{0.33333\linewidth}{0.5pt}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
            \initem [$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$]
                    {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
            \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
            \initem [$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$]
                    {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
            \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$
            \initem [$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$]
                    {$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en) package is designed for this.  You should use it.

Here's how to apply it to your example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textheight=21cm,textwidth=16cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\initem}{\ifnum\enit@type=\z@\refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
                     \hspace{20pt}\@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Example 1 -- Two columns \\
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+5x-1$
    \item $f(x)= \frac{x+3}{2x-4}$
    \item   $f(x)= \sqrt{3x-12}$
    \item $f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{6-2x}}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\vspace{1cm}


Example 2 -- Three columns \\
\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.334\linewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+1$
    \item $f(x)= \frac{x+3}{2x-4}$
    \item $f(x)= \sqrt{3x-12}$
    \item   $f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$
    \item $f(x)= \frac{x}{x+1}$
    \item $f(x)= \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Original example**
Here's an example combined with `threeparttable`'s `tablenotes` to demonstrate its use with a list. It's lifted from my thesis, to illustrate the output; the part of most interest is between `\begin{multicols}[2]` and `\end{multicols}`.  It works nicely with more conventional `\item`s as well:
[image: multicols example output]

```
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption[High\hyp{}frequency\hyp{}related material parameters.]{\label{tab_Theory_Materials}High\hyp{}frequency\hyp{}related material parameters.  Based on a table in reference \citenumns{Mishra_RF_Amps}, some data from reference \citenumns{Willardson_SiC}.}
\small{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}}
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$E_g$\tnote{a}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$n_i$\tnote{b}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\epsilon_r$\tnote{c}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu_n$\tnote{d}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$v_\mathrm{sat}$\tnote{e}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$E_\mathrm{br}$\tnote{f}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mathit{TC}$\tnote{g}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mathit{JM}$\tnote{h}}\\
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\si{\eV}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\si{\cm^{-3}}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\si{\cm\per\volt\per\s}}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{$\times 10^7$\si{\cm\per\s}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\si{\mega\volt\per\cm}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\Wmk}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
    \midrule\\
    Si&1.1&1.5e10&11.8&1350&1.0&0.3&150&1\\
    %\sisetup{scientific-notation=true}
    GaAs&1.42&1.5e5&13.1&8500&1.0&0.6&43&2.7\\
    %\sisetup{scientific-notation=false}
    SiC (4H)&3.26&8.2e-9&10&700&2.0&3.0&450\tnote{~i}&20\\
    GaN&3.4&1.9e-10&9.0&2000\tnote{~j}&2.5&3.3&130&27.5\\
    Diamond&5.4&1.6e-27&5.5&1900&2.7&5.6&2000&50\\
    \bottomrule 

\end{tabular}}
\begin{tablenotes}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0cm}
    \begin{multicols}{2}\raggedright
        \item[a] Bandgap.
        \item[b] \rep{Intrinsic c}{C}arrier density \add{at room temperature}.
        \item[c] Relative permittivity.
        \item[d] Electron mobility.
        \item[e] Saturation velocity.
        \item[f] Breakdown field. 
        \item[g] \Acl{TC} \add{at room temperature. The \acl{TC} reduces with temperature at typical operating temperatures,\supercite{Luo_TC_T} for GaN $\mathit{TC}\propto T^{-1.4}$ is often used, though values vary}.
        \item[h] Johnson figure of merit, which compares the power\hyp{}frequency performance of materials, normalised to the value for Si. $JM=\rfrac{E_\mathrm{br}v_\mathrm{sat}}{2\pi}$.
        \item[i] In-plane; parallel to the $c$-axis the \acl{TC} is 330~\Wmk.
        \item[j] Within the \acs{2DEG}; the bulk value is \SI[scientific-notation=false]{1200}{\cm\per\volt\per\s}.
    \end{multicols}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
```

Comment: Is your answer intended for this question?

Comment: @Zarko yes: use multicols around the enumerate, as I use it round my list

Comment: well, op explicitly say that it not like to use `multicol` nor `task` package. Also items  contain math expression which should be should be aligned.

Comment: ... I could cook up a simpler example, but had one that demonstrates the features

Comment: @Zarko I missed the OP's "I don't want to use a very suitable package".  I'll see if I can quickly demonstrate why it's good for the OP's example

Comment: The multicol package doesn't align the items vertically due to maths and the numbering is vertical, not horizontal as I prefer. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I noticed the horizontal numbering, but vertical is more common in the tests I'm used to. Your comment is much clearer about the vertical alignment than your question. A macro defining a phantom that's the tallest and deepest equation, inserted in each item, would solve that. I can't give an example on mobile but will of you're interested - I suspect not as you want horizontal numbering.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you not like `tasks` package and till to now doesn't say, why not liked it (I ask for this in my comment). Also  the purposes of horizontal rules, which you show, is unclear.

However, for the cases as you show in your question, the `tasks` package has been developed. With it you can simply align items horisontaly as well verticaly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textheight=21cm,textwidth=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
    label = \arabic*.
        }

\begin{document}

Example 1 -- Two columns 
    \begin{tasks}(2)
\task   $f(x) = 2x^3-3x^2+5x-1$
\task   $f(x) = \dfrac{x+3}{2x-4}$
\task   $f(x) = \sqrt{3x-12}$
\task   $f(x) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{6-2x}}$
    \end{tasks}

\vspace{1cm}

Example 2 -- Three columns 
    \begin{tasks}(3)
\task   $f(x) = 2x^3-3x^2+1$
\task   $f(x) = \dfrac{x+3}{2x-4}$
\task   $f(x) = \sqrt{3x-12}$
\task   $f(x) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$
\task   $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x+1}$
\task   $f(x) = \sqrt{x+\dfrac{1}{x}}$
    \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Similar result with use of the `eninumitem` package is very difficult if even impossible to achieve. However, similar result without use of `tasks` package you can obtain with use of an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

Example 1 -- Two columns 

$\displaystyle
    \begin{array}{cc @{\qquad} cc}
1.  &  f(x) = 2x^3-3x^2+5x-1    & 2.&  f(x) = \dfrac{x+3}{2x-4}    \\
    \addlinespace
3.  &  f(x) = \sqrt{3x-12}      & 4.&  f(x) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{6-2x}}
    \end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I keep that this is very difficult with the `enumitem` package. There is no specific reason I don't use  the `tasks` package. My question was how can I align the items in enumerate environment not which package to use for this.

Comment: I clearly say, that this is very difficult or even impossible. `enumitem` has not be designed for such purposes, but `tasks` has been. So, it is difficult to understand, why you not like to use right tools, and persist with one, which is not and consequently causes to you only problems.

Comment: I don't disagree with you! I use both of them but I was wondering how I could do it with the `enumitem` package. Anyway thank you for your time again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a far from perfect way to do this without any additionnal package.  IMO, the `tasks` package is a better way to do it.

You could put your equation in a box of a fixed width. By choosing the right value for the width of the box, you could be close to the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textheight=21cm,textwidth=16cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\initem}{\ifnum\enit@type=\z@\refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
                    \@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\mylength}    % define a length for the width of the box
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\makebox[\mylength][l]{#1}}    % define a command to make it easier to change things

\begin{document}

Example 1 -- Two columns \\
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\mylength}{205pt}    % approximate width needed
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  \mybox{$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+5x-1$}
    \initem  \mybox{$f(x)= \frac{x+3}{2x-4}$}
    \item    \mybox{$f(x)= \sqrt{3x-12}$}
    \initem  \mybox{$f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{6-2x}}$}
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{1cm}

Example 2 -- Three columns \\
\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.334\linewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\mylength}{135pt}    % approximate width needed
\begin{enumerate}
    \item    \mybox{$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+1$}
    \initem  \mybox{$f(x)= \frac{x+3}{2x-4}$}
    \initem  \mybox{$f(x)= \sqrt{3x-12}$}
    \item    \mybox{$f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$}
    \initem  \mybox{$f(x)= \frac{x}{x+1}$}
    \initem  \mybox{$f(x)= \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}}$}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The value `205pt` and `135pt` have been found by trial and error and are not a perfect fit.  Maybe there is a way to improve this by using the `calc` package.

Comment: Thank you very much! All the answers were useful to me especially with the new command `\mybox`.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this with the `tabularx` package.  It is a piece of code I found on the internet a few years back (I sadly don't remember where).  I used it a lot until I switch to the `tasks` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textheight=21cm,textwidth=16cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{row}
\renewcommand{\therow}{\arabic{row}}
\newenvironment{rowenum}[1]
    {\setcounter{row}{0}%
        \par\noindent\tabularx{\linewidth}[t]
        {*{#1}{>{\stepcounter{row}\makebox[1.8em][r]{\therow.\hspace{0.5em}}}X}}%
    }
    {\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

Example 1 -- Two columns \\
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{rowenum}{2}
    $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+5x-1$   &$f(x)= \frac{x+3}{2x-4}$\\
   $f(x)= \sqrt{3x-12}$   &$f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{6-2x}}$
\end{rowenum}

\vspace{1cm}

Example 2 -- Three columns \\
\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\hphantom{\rule{0.333\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\rule{0.334\linewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{rowenum}{3}
   $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+1$   &$f(x)= \frac{x+3}{2x-4}$   &$f(x)= \sqrt{3x-12}$\\
   $f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$   &$f(x)= \frac{x}{x+1}$   &$f(x)= \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}}$
\end{rowenum}

\end{document}
```

`tabularx` create a table as large as the textwidth.  This table is split into how many cell we need (required argument).  Every cell start with a number, using a latex counter.

This is not the perfect solution.  I always tought that the line were too close.  I had to manually adjust the line spacing to make it easier to read.  It was a lot of work.